# Prometheus blackbox exporter citing several modules per job

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-blackbox-exporter

What is the semantics of a `job` for a Prometheus blackbox exporter that cites more than one module under `params.module`?

I guess it means that all modules are tried and the probe only succeeds if all of them succeed. All the examples I have come across employ only single modules (typically [`module: [http_2xx]`](https://github.com/prometheus/blackbox_exporter)), and I have not configured an example nor looked it up in the source code so far. Maybe someone here knows already/definitely from direct experience.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the `blackbox_exporter` source code it would seem that every probe only ever executes a single test / module. Either you provide the module name in the request (as [suggested](https://github.com/prometheus/blackbox_exporter#prometheus-configuration) by the documentation) or else it defaults to `http_2xx`.

The only way you could execute multiple modules would appear to be to define a separate Prometheus job, with a different `module` parameter value.

The only reason Prometheus' `params` is an array rather than a single value is that it's not limited to `blackbox_exporter`, it's a general way of sending HTTP parameters to a target (e.g. one might use something like `/metrics?module=foo&module=bar` to instruct the target to only return metrics for modules `foo` and `bar`).

I just tested from the browser and what happens if you query `blackbox_exporter` with multiple `module` parameter values, is that `blackbox_exporter` will ignore everything but the first value.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense: "The only reason Prometheus' `params` is an array rather than a single value is that it's not limited to `blackbox_exporter`..."

Answer (score 0):

You can configure multiple Blackbox Exporter modules in one job:

Forget defining the single `module` param for the `job` (although there would be a default http_2xx anyway).
Instead, add a `__param_module` label to each of the different `static_config` lists.

Example from [the forum post](https://groups.google.com/g/prometheus-users/c/93w9nMLD2AM/m/pODP3PEMBAAJ)

```
static_configs:
  - targets: [ url1, url2, url3 ]
    labels:  { __param_module: http_2xx }

  - targets: [ 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4 ]
    labels:  { __param_module: icmp }
```

Another improvement could be to use the label `module` instead of `__param_module`.
This way the `module` appears as a label in the Prometheus metrics.
Of course, in this case you have to extend the
[usual](https://prometheus.io/docs/guides/multi-target-exporter/#querying-multi-target-exporters-with-prometheus)
`relabel_configs` with a new item:

```
relabel_configs:
  - source_labels:  [__address__]
    target_label:   instance
  - source_labels:  [__address__]
    target_label:   __param_target

  - source_labels:  [module]
    target_label:   __param_module

  - target_label:   __address__
    replacement:    localhost:9115
```